# Extracting the URL attribute from a enclosure tag

Tags: objective-c, gdata

Im using GDataXML to parse a XML feed (RSS) in an Iphone App.
I need the url attr in the enclosure tag.
Can GdataXML do this or must I change to NSXML.
I have searched extensively and cant find any info on doing this in objc
and with GDataXML.

The tag looks like  < enclosure url="http://www.i ......./>

I have been successful reading the sub elements under < item> 
with:
NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];

but I don't know which direction to go in anymore to get the url inside the enclosure.

If anyone has any info or could point in the right direction, it would great, as time is 
against us.

Thanks again